# Insert multiple html elements based on dynamic values, into different DIVs using javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out what I need to do.

I'm working on a small train timetable app which finds the five closest stations and brings up the timetables for all five stations. I have successfully found the nearest stations, and have managed to get all the service information from each of the stations. I have used datasets on the wrapper element for each station as a way to insert the correct service information to each wrapper.

The problem I'm facing now, is that at the moment I have all of the service box elements being placed in to the first wrapper. Is there a way to insert the service box elements in to the correct DIVs?

The API I am working with provides a unique 3 character station code (e.g. FST etc.), as well as the API I have used to find stations nearby.

e.g I have 5 stations with the codes AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD and AAE. All AAA stations should be inserted in to the respective DIV with the AAA dataset, same with AAB... etc...

I am using the TransportAPI if you need to know.

See the Javascript code I have so far. Thanks in advance.

```js
// scripts

// change protocol to https if http
if (window.location.protocol != 'https:') window.location.protocol = 'https';

// 
var info = document.querySelector(".info");

// check if geolocation works/is supported using if statement
// if geolocation is supported
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {

    // log to console
    console.log("GeoLocation is working.");

    // function to run if geolocation is supported
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        // store users coords
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        // log them to console
        console.log("Your coordinates are: " + lat + "," + lon);

        // callback function to use users coordinates in another function
        findNearestStation(lat, lon);

    });

    // if geolocation is not supported
} else {

    // log to console
    console.log("GeoLocation is not supported.");
}

function findNearestStation(lat, lon) {

    console.log("Your coordinates are: " + lat + "," + lon);

    // api keys and tokens
    var appID = "xxxxx";
    var appKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // api for nearest stations url template
    var transportApiUrl = "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/stations/near.json?app_id=" + appID + "&app_key=" + appKey + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&rpp=5";

    // ajax request to get nearest stations
    var nearbyStationsReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    nearbyStationsReq.open('GET', transportApiUrl, true);

    nearbyStationsReq.onload = function() {

        // results window
        var resultsWindow = document.querySelector(".results-window");

        // empty array for the timetable urls
        var timetableUrlArray = [];
        // empty array for station codes
        var stationCodeArray = [];

        // clear the results window
        resultsWindow.innerHTML = "";

        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            // response data
            var res = JSON.parse(this.response);

            // variable for stations array in response
            var data = res.stations;

            // for loop to iterate through response data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                // get information from response data
                var code = data[i].station_code;
                var name = data[i].name;
                var distanceMetres = data[i].distance;
                var distanceKilometres = (distanceMetres / 1000).toFixed(1);
                var distanceKilometres = distanceKilometres + "km";

                // log data to console to reference
                console.log("Code: " + code + " | Name: " + name + " | Distance: " + distanceKilometres);

                // generate urls for timetable data
                var timetableUrl = "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/" + code + "/live.json?app_id=" + appID + "&app_key=" + appKey + "&darwin=true&train_status=passenger";

                // push completed urls to the array
                timetableUrlArray.push(timetableUrl);

                // push codes to empty array
                stationCodeArray.push(code);

                // template for nearest stations result container
                var resultTemplate =
                    "<div class='result'>" +
                    "<div class='station-name'>" +
                    "<span class='service-origin'>" +
                    "<span class='nr-logo'>" +
                    "<img src='assets/images/nr.svg' alt='National Rail Logo'></span>" + name + "</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='service-results-wrapper' data-stationcode='" + code + "'></div>" +
                    "</div>";

                // insert template in to the results window
                resultsWindow.innerHTML += resultTemplate;

            }

            // log to console
            console.log(stationCodeArray)

            // for loop to create a request for each station
            for (var i = 0; i < timetableUrlArray.length; i++) {

                // ajax request for timetable request
                var timetableReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                timetableReq.open('GET', timetableUrlArray[i], true);

                timetableReq.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                        // response from request
                        var res = JSON.parse(this.response);

                        // data for timetable info
                        var data = res.departures.all;

                        // declare service results wrapper
                        var serviceResultsWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".service-results-wrapper");

                        // loop to go through the data
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            // information required
                            var currentStation = res.station_name;
                            var currentStationCode = res.station_code;
                            var aimedDepartTime = data[i].aimed_departure_time;
                            var expectedDepartTime = data[i].expected_departure_time;
                            var destination = data[i].destination_name;
                            var platform = data[i].platform;
                            var operator = data[i].operator_name;
                            var status = data[i].status;
                            var trainUID = data[i].train_uid;

                            // log data to console
                            console.log("Current Station: " + currentStation + " | Current Station Code: " + currentStationCode + " | Aimed: " + aimedDepartTime + " | Expected: " + expectedDepartTime + " | Destination: " + destination + " | Platform: " + platform + " | Status: " + status + " | Operator: " + operator + " | ID: " + trainUID);

                            // template for service boxes
                            var serviceBoxTemplate = "<span class='service-box'><span class='service-time-status'><span class='service-depart-time'>" + aimedDepartTime + "</span>" +
                                "<span class='service-depart-status'>" + currentStation + "</span>" +
                                "<span class='service-depart-platform'>Plat. <span class='service-platform-number'>" + platform + "</span></span></span>" +
                                "<span class='service-destination'><span class='service-destination-name'>" + destination + "</span></span>" +
                                "<span class='calling stations'>Leigh-on-Sea, Chalkwell, Westcliff, Southend Central, Southend East, Thorpe Bay, Shoeburyness</span>" +
                                "<span class='service-operator'>Operated by <span class='service-operator-by'>" + operator + "</span></div>";

                            serviceResultsWrapper[0].innerHTML += serviceBoxTemplate;

                        }

                    } else {
                        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                    }
                };

                timetableReq.onerror = function() {
                    // There was a connection error of some sort
                };

                timetableReq.send();

            }

        } else {
            // log to console
            console.log("There is an error.");

        }
    };

    nearbyStationsReq.onerror = function() {

        // log to console
        console.log("There is an error.");


    };

    nearbyStationsReq.send();

}
```

Comment: As a hint, don't do this `resultsWindow.innerHTML += resultTemplate`, it may be insecure to use innerHTML to modify the DOM and i edited your question to remove your api key and token.

Comment: @cyrix what would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `findNearestStation`, the code `serviceResultsWrapper[0].innerHTML += serviceBoxTemplate;` inserts the service box to the `div.service-results-wrapper` of the **first** `div.result`. You should replace that code with something like this:

```
let currentWrapper = [...serviceResultsWrapper].find((wrapper) => wrapper.dataset.stationcode === currentStationCode);
let serviceBoxFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(serviceBoxTemplate);

currentWrapper.appendChild(serviceBoxFragment);
```